# Representing train schedules in a matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a question here that has no answer from the lecture notes, so I'm turning here to ask for help.
The question goes like this:

> Let  $t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4$ represent 4 different towns in a large country. Consider that there are the following:
>
> 1-way service from $t_1$ to $t_2$ and $t_3$
>
> 1-way service from $t_2$ to $t_3$ and $t_4$ and
>
> 2-way services between the towns $t_1$ and $t_4$
>
> Write out a matrix $S$ such that $[S]_{ij} = 1$ if there is a train ride from  $t_i$ to $t_j$ and $0$ otherwise.

How will a person approach this question? I would consider a $4 \times 4$ matrix (please ignore 1st row & 1st column...it's not a $5 \times 5$ matrix).

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
* & t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4
\\
t_1 & * & * & * & *
\\
t_2 & * & * & * & *
\\
t_3 & * & * & * & *
\\
t_4 & * & * & * & *
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And fill them according, resulting in

$$S = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is this the final answer, or should the answer be transposed?

Comment: That's some strange timetable. Does the consist the has worked the 1-2-3 service return to 2 as empty stock so it can become the 2-3-4 service? And then return nonstop to 1 as a 4-1 service? How is that a meaningful service pattern? How do _people_ who travel from 2 to 3 get back home?

Comment: I had to modify the question a little to prevent Google from picking the original question up. The original question involved countries and flights.

Comment: I would write START on the left and END at the top (or vice versa if transposed), but don't have strong feelings on which orientation is better.

Comment: Hello Ross Millikan, I am being constrained by the $ij$ part of the question, where, as you can see from the answer, is $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\{ij\}^{th}$ element of the matrix will in the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column. So your answer $$S = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1
\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

is correct.